# Django 2: path('^$', home, name='home') not working

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls, django-2.0

I am new to Django and trying to make a project, but I am facing a simple problem. I am writing a path in Django 2 for root and it's not working, but for other things it works. Can anyone point out why it's not working.

What is working:

```
path(r'home/', home, name='home'),
```

This is not working:

```
path(r'^$', home, name='home'),
```

And just to be clear: I am not loading both the line together. I comment one line at a time, so no order issues.

Comment: which one is working `http://example.com/` or `http://example.com` ? or neither is working

Comment: path('/home', home, name='home') is working but that route should be for home.But what i am trying is to make a route for root but thats not working.

something similar to this
url(r'^$', home, name='home') # which works in django 1.8
but in django 2 url doesnt work they added path
for root what should i write

Comment: This one `path(r'^$', home, name='home'),` works for either of the two path I mentioned in above comment so I am asking when you do `http://localhost:8000` it works or not?. Does it work when you type `http://localhost:8000/` in the browser? slashes matters here

Comment: No @ArpitSolanki thats not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beginning with Django 2 a new way of defining URL routes is introduced. There are the functions `path` and `re_path`.

You seem to mix some things. Here is how it should look like when using `path`:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    # or
    path('home/', home, name='home'),
]
```

From this example you can obviously use only one `path`. I gave them both for illustrating.
As you notice the paths aren't raw strings and don't contain regular expressions like `^` or `$`.

For using regular expressions use `re_path`.

Comment: @You're welcome. Please invest some time and accomplish the official [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/). It will help you to understand the basics of Django 2 and its new features.

Comment: thanks again for tutorial, and i was looking for video tutorials but all on youtube are mostly for django 1.8-9 so couldn't get help. But thanks man for help